# Javascript not waiting for processing before proceeding trying callbacks and promises

Tags: javascript, file, directory, callback

I have looked at a bunch of promise tutorials and callback tutorials, and I guess I just don't get something.  My code below reads all of the files in a directory and processes those files.  When it is over I need it to call writeToFile() .. but writeToFile gets calls before the processing is done.  I hope this post can finally end my confusion.  Thank you.  Code below:

```
function go(callbackFunction){
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readdir('./filesToProcess', (err, files) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      //console.log("run the process on : " + files[i]);
      console.log("Processing: " + files[i] + "\n");
      processFile('./filesToProcess/' + files[i]);
    };

  });
  callbackFunction();
}

go(writeToFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for your function to finish let me explain promises

```js
const foo = async () =>{ /* some function that takes time */}


// If I call foo like this "as you did inside the go function"

foo()
console.log("After foo")

//The console.log will print before the foo execute because you didn't wait for it
//The correct way is

await foo()
console.log("After foo")

//or

foo().then(() => console.log("After foo") )
```

to know more about how to use promises go [Here](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Async / Await

```
Async function go(){...
await fs.readdir(...
}
```

Or if fs.readdir return a promise you can do this like that:

```
function go(callback){
fs.readdir('./filesToProcess', (err, files) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      //console.log("run the process on : " + files[i]);
      console.log("Processing: " + files[i] + "\n");
      processFile('./filesToProcess/' + files[i]);
    };

  }).then(callback (){})
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is move callbackFunction into the callback you pass to readdir, that way you'll make sure it's ONLY executed when the processing is done.

```
function go(callbackFunction){
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readdir('./filesToProcess', (err, files) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      //console.log("run the process on : " + files[i]);
      console.log("Processing: " + files[i] + "\n");
      processFile('./filesToProcess/' + files[i]);
    };
    **callbackFunction();**    
  });

}

go(writeToFile);
```